# C++: Adição das implementações ".cpp" em Visual Studio e GCC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

Em C++, o que se observa em uma pesquisa rápida pela internet é a orientação de que apenas arquivos ".h" devem ser incluídos. Um amostra disso pode ser observado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253786/include-cpp-instead-of-header-h) e especialmente [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242229/como-incluir-header-e-cpp-sem-resultar-em-erro-lnk2005-no-visual-studio).

No Visual Studio, a inclusão de **apenas** ".h" com `#include ...` não gera problema, desde que os arquivos de implementação ".cpp" estejam incluídos no projeto. Isso garante que eles serão compilados e haverá uma ***referência*** válida para os métodos da classe. Porém, este não parece ser o caso para o GCC (g++). Veja o código abaixo:

### Mt.h

```
#ifndef MT_H
#define MT_H

namespace Subsistema {
  class Mt {
  public:
    int soma(int i, int d);
  };
}
#endif
```

### Mt.cpp

```
#include "Mt.h"

namespace Subsistema {
    int Mt::soma(int i, int d) {
    return i + d;
  }
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Mt.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  Subsistema::Mt * t = new Subsistema::Mt();

  std::cout << "Soma: " << t->soma(3, 5) << std::endl;

  delete t;

  return 0;
}
```

O código acima, compilará perfeitamente em Visual Studio mesmo não havendo um `#include Mt.cpp`, desde que o mesmo esteja incluído no projeto. Porém NÃO o fará em **g++**, com a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> /tmp/ccQVvF4r.o: In function 'main':
>
> main.cpp:7: **undefined reference** to 'Subsistema::Mt::soma(int, int)'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Esse erro poderia facilmente ser resolvido, adicionando a macro `#ifdef __GNUC__` , da seguinte forma:

```
#ifndef MT_H
#define MT_H

namespace Subsistema {
  class Mt {
  public:
    int soma(int i, int d);
  };
}

#ifdef __GNUC__
#include "Mt.cpp"
#endif

#endif
```

Mas o ponto é, esse é uma solução, mas é a solução adequada (melhor prática) para a situação? Eu necessito de uma solução, que na medida do possível, **independa** do compilador usado.

*NOTA: Esta pergunta está intimamente relacionada com [Como incluir header e cpp sem resultar em erro LNK2005 no Visual Studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242229/como-incluir-header-e-cpp-sem-resultar-em-erro-lnk2005-no-visual-studio)*

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem de erro não é um erro de compilação. Trata-se de um erro de *linkagem*:

```
/tmp/ccQVvF4r.o: In function 'main':
main.cpp:7: undefined reference to 'Subsistema::Mt::soma(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Significa que o `linker` não está encontrado o arquivo objeto contendo a implementação do método `Subsistema::Mt::soma(int, int)`.

O `Mt.cpp` deve ser passado como parametro para o compilador e não incluido por meio da diretiva `#include`.

Isso deve compilar seu programa sem erros:

```
$ g++ main.cpp Mt.cpp -o teste
```

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado. Mas é serio isso? Se eu tiver um projeto com mais de 50 .cpp, terei que passar todos eles no commando do gcc? Nossa, desculpe a surpresa, mas isso nao me parece coerente, pelo contrario, contra producente. Nao ha uma alternativa mais limpa e automatizada?

Comment: Em projetos grandes nao se compila manualmente assim. Para isso se usam os famosos makefiles

Comment: @guinalz eu fiz uma resposta sobre o uso de `makefile`s em um projeto, e também envolve uma ou duas coisinhas de ciclo de compilação de arquivos C: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213804/64969; para C++, o comportamento é muito similar. Também tem mais diversas coisas bacanas para se usar com `makefile` de modo mais avançado, que você mal escreve o arquivo de `make`, mas isso normalmente é um uso mais avançado que você sentirá a necessidade depois. Quando você sentir a necessidade de coisas mais avançadas, estaremos por aqui

Comment: Explicação do que é o Makefile: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154102/64969