# Undefined reference to

Tags: c, funções, codeblocks

Tenho um programa que está dividido em sua `main`, `city.c` e `city.h`.

Main:

```
#include "city.h"


int main()
{
    FILE *entrada;
    FILE *saida;
    Cidade *cidades;


    entrada = fopen("entrada.c", "r");

    int numeroCidades = LeNumeroDeCidades(entrada);
    LeCidades(entrada, &cidades, numeroCidades);
    fclose(entrada);

    saida = fopen("saida.c", "w");

    Possibilidades(saida, numeroCidades);
    int sequencia[numeroCidades];
    int totalViagens = TotalViagens(numeroCidades);
    MenorRota(saida, cidades, sequencia, numeroCidades, totalViagens);
    fclose(saida);


    return 0;
}
```

City.c:

```
#include "city.h"

(Todas as funções e seus corpos)...
```

City.h:

```
#ifndef CITY_H_INCLUDED
#define CITY_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define INFINITO 9999999

/*----STRUCT----*/
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Cidade;

/*---------FUNÇÕES---------*/
void CriaCidade(Cidade *, int , int);
int LeNumeroDeCidades(FILE *);
void LeCidades(FILE *, Cidade **, int);
float Distancia(Cidade *, int, int *);
int TotalViagens(int);
void Troca(int *, int *);
void GeraRotaseDistancias(FILE *, Cidade *, int *, int, int, int, float *, float *);
void CriaSequencia(int, int *);
void MenorRota(FILE *, Cidade *, int *, int, int);
void Possibilidades(FILE *, int);

#endif // CITY_H_INCLUDED
```

Ao compilar, recebo o mesmo problema para todas as funções:

```
||=== Build: Debug in city (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\Users\windows\city\main.c|13|undefined reference to `LeNumeroDeCidades'|
C:\Users\windows\city\main.c|14|undefined reference to `LeCidades'|
C:\Users\windows\city\main.c|19|undefined reference to `Possibilidades'|
C:\Users\windows\city\main.c|21|undefined reference to `TotalViagens'|
C:\Users\windows\city\main.c|22|undefined reference to `MenorRota'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|
```

Gostaria de saber o que está gerando este problema.

Comment: Erro de linkagem. Conhece Makefile?

Comment: Não conheço, Jefferson

Comment: Compilo usando o CodeBlocks

Comment: Se o teu projeto for somente esses 3 arquivos, e estiver usando Linux, tenta executar essa linha na pasta do projeto, onde estao os arquivos: `gcc -o main city.c main.c` e ve se funciona

Comment: Faz bem conhecer o ciclo de vida da compilação de um programa em C. Essa resposta fala disso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213804/64969 ; creio que você possa ensinar ao codeblocks a usar um Makefile para compilar (o Makefile é o foco da pergunta da resposta linkada). Creio que o codeblocks também tenha uma configuração de projeto sem o Makefile algum, que neste caso não está configurado para fazer a linkagem do `main` com os demais arquivos objetos

Comment: O estranho é que eu já fiz essa forma de separação dos arquivos .c e .h outras vezes e nunca deu esse tipo de problema. Mas com esse exemplo, deu erro. Isso é normal?

Comment: Colocando os corpos das funções no arquivo .h, o problema deixa de existir. Há uma explicação?

Comment: Sim, tem uma explicação. Você leu a resposta que eu linkei? Está lá a explicação, e também o porquê isso é uma aberração da natureza. Em suma? Deixe header ter apenas declaração, sem implementação

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/243516/64969

Comment: Tu criou o projeto no CodeBlocks ou somente tentou compilar/executar o main.c?

Comment: Eu criei o projeto sim. Consegui consertar o problema. Obrigado a todos